# IKImageBrowserView and ImageTitle

Tags: ikimagebrowserview, ikimageview

I have a imagebrowserview displaying a folder full of photo correctly but its not showing the image title of each of the photo ...

is there a tutorial to show me how this works?

Regards

AGW

Answer (score 1):

Titles are not displayed by default, even if you provide the data.  You need to turn them on by calling setCellsStyleMask on the IKImageBrowserView object.

```
[imageBrowserView setCellsStyleMask:IKCellsStyleTitled];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IKImageBrowserItem items simply need to supply a title and/or subtitle. Take a look at the Apple sample code "ImageKitDemo" for an example.